# Using XLNet for sentiment analysis - setting the correct reshape parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis, huggingface-transformers

Following  [this link](https://medium.com/swlh/using-xlnet-for-sentiment-classification-cfa948e65e85), I am trying to use my own data to do sentiment analysis. But I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

<ipython-input-41-5f2f35b7976e> in train_epoch(model, data_loader, optimizer, device, scheduler, n_examples)
      7 
      8     for d in data_loader:
----> 9         input_ids = d["input_ids"].reshape(4,64).to(device)
     10         attention_mask = d["attention_mask"].to(device)
     11         targets = d["targets"].to(device)

RuntimeError: shape '[4, 64]' is invalid for input of size 64
```

When I try to run this code

```
history = defaultdict(list)
best_accuracy = 0

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{EPOCHS}')
    print('-' * 10)

    train_acc, train_loss = train_epoch(
        model,
        train_data_loader,     
        optimizer, 
        device, 
        scheduler, 
        len(df_train)
    )

    print(f'Train loss {train_loss} Train accuracy {train_acc}')

    val_acc, val_loss = eval_model(
        model,
        val_data_loader, 
        device, 
        len(df_val)
    )

    print(f'Val loss {val_loss} Val accuracy {val_acc}')
    print()

    history['train_acc'].append(train_acc)
    history['train_loss'].append(train_loss)
    history['val_acc'].append(val_acc)
    history['val_loss'].append(val_loss)
```

I know this error has something to do with the shape of my data but I am not sure how to find the correct `reshape` parameters in order to make this work.

Comment: What are the values `4` and `64`represent for your case?

Comment: Can you please provide the minimal code sufficient to reproduce your problem?

Comment: In order to get useful answers, I suggest posting your full code with imports. We need to know how the function train_epoch expects its arguments. The error you stated is clearly about the dimensions of your training dataset. `d["input_ids"] ` probably can't be reshaped to [4,64]. Post a sample of your data, then we'll help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shape [4,64] in your example is actually [batch size, max_sequence_length]

So maybe you could replace them with your values...

Answer (score 0):

However you haven't posted your sample data but it is evident that how you are using your `reshape` [function](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html). With respect to your question to `reshape` `d["input_ids"]` into shape `(4,64)` then  `d["input_ids"]` should be an array of size `256` but actually in your dataset which you are feeding the model with is of size `64`

So you need to reshape `d["input_ids"]` with something like `(1,64) or (2,32) or (4,16)` etc as per how your data is, whose multiple is 64.

Just illustrate the same:

```
>>> a = np.arange(256).reshape(4,64)
>>> a
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,
         13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,
         26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,
         39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,
         52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63],
       [ 64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,
         77,  78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,
         90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102,
        103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115,
        116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127],
       [128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140,
        141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153,
        154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166,
        167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179,
        180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191],
       [192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204,
        205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217,
        218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230,
        231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243,
        244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255]])
```